# Python can't connect to mysql using docker

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I'm new to docker and right now I'm trying to use mysql in my mac without install it so I wanted to use Docker but I keep getting this error

*sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (61 Connection refused)*

**Reproduce the problem:**

I pulled mysql/mysql-server:

```
docker pull mysql/mysql-server
```

Inside the terminal:

```
docker run --name=mydb -d mysql/mysql-server
```

Then I changed its password into :123456

Inside the code database.py:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://mydb:123456@localhost:3306/authorize_info'
```

At this step I will get this error

*sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (61 Connection refused)*

I also got this error when I changed 'localhost' into '172.17.0.1'

Where am I wrong and how to fix it? Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a container, it doesn't automatically map its ports to the ports on your machine. You need to tell docker what the port in the container should be mapped to on your local machine by using the `-p` option. If you want to be able to access port 3306 in the container by using port 3306 on your local machine, you should start the container like this

```
docker run --name=mydb -d -p 3306:3306 mysql/mysql-server
```

The first number is the port on your local machine and the second number is the port in the container.

Comment: Thank you. I got some progress, now it shows this error:
_sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query_

Answer (score 0):

there is one more thing. you can user name of a container to connect if if your app is in the same network as database. if not, you should use host IP to connect to the database.